# Java iText and custom Radiobutton behaviour

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText 2.1.7. 
I have three radiobuttons in a table cell.

Initial all buttons (b1, b2 and b3) are unchecked.

Desired behaviour:

If Check b1: b2 & b3 to uncheck

If Check b2: b1 to uncheck

If Check b3: b1 to uncheck

So b2 and b3 can be checked at the same time.

Additionally i want that all buttons can be toggled to off again.

How can i achieve that behaviour? 
Help appreciated!

Comment: That sounds like it requires JavaScript in the pdf.

Comment: Christian, are you still interested in this? I neither see you reacting to my comment (as JavaScript is not active in all viewers, using JavaScript might not be an option for you) nor to @Lonzak's answer (which actually is not an answer but a request for clarification).

Answer (score 1):

Before I fully answer your question have a look a the example behavior - is that what you want? Do you have an PDF with existing fields or do you want to newly add those fields?

[image: Click behaviour]

The solution does not use javascript.

```
1. Create a checkbox with 3 kids
1 0 obj
<</DA(/ZaDb 0 Tf 0 g)/FT/Btn/Kids[14 0 R 19 0 R 24 0 R]/T(checkbox1)>>
endobj

2. Create the 3 kids with values 1xb1 and 2xb2
14 0 obj
<</AP<</b1 18 0 R>>/N<</Off 15 0 R/b1 16 0 R>>>>/AS/Off/F 4/MK<</CA(8)>>/P 12 0 R/Parent 1 0 R/Rect[122 723 140 740]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj

19 0 obj
<</AP<</b2 23 0 R>>/N<</Off 20 0 R/b2 21 0 R>>>>/AS/Off/F 4/MK<</CA(8)>>/P 12 0 R/Parent 1 0 R/Rect[145 722 162 739]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj

24 0 obj
<</AP<</b2 28 0 R>>/N<</Off 25 0 R/b2 26 0 R>>>>/AS/Off/F 4/MK<</CA(8)>>/P 12 0 R/Parent 1 0 R/Rect[167 721 185 738]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj
```

Update: You can find the solution how to completely add new checkoxes to a PDF [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-creating-form-fields).

Comment: No really an answer... kind of a `Promise<Answer>`... ;)

Comment: yeah I know but I didn't know how to add an image to an comment :-)

Comment: By the way, I think the OP wants something slightly different, he said he wanted that *b2 and b3 **can** be checked at the same time* which to me allows them also to be checked separately, so that e.g. b2 is on and b3 is off. Your image seems to not allow that. (For what the image shows, I think JavaScript is not necessary.)

Comment: Yeah so for me checking b2 and b3 means that they  are checked at the same time. That is why I answered partly witha a question....And yes, no JS.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yes i still need a solution for this. The example behaviour is correct and desired. Still no idea how to implement. b2 & b3 can be active the same time. No dependence between b2 & b3, but between b1 and (b2 + b3):