# PDF-Checkbox - check one and uncheck another without JavaScript

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

in my project I need 3 checkboxes which should work like radiobuttons. But radiobuttons have some drawbacks with appearance in Adobe Reader. For this reason I have to use checkboxes. There is a very interesting answer, but I don't understand how this can be done with iText:

[Java iText and custom Radiobutton behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351203/java-itext-and-custom-radiobutton-behaviour)

Can anybody -- especially Lonzak, the author of this posting -- help me in this case. Thanks and Kind regards, Dirk

Comment: Hey Tim Cook lookalike ;-) There are no differences regarding Radiobutton and Checkbox appearances. (Or what is the problem? All can be cross, check, circle, diamond, square, star ... etc)  I mean there is the possibility to "emulate" radiobutton behaviour with checkboxes however the difference is more in behaviour than in appeareance. So maybe you can share a bit more about your problem first...

Comment: Everybody is telling me that, even in the supermarket :-( but I'm not!!!
In my project I create PDFs with iText 7 for Java. In Adobe Reader Radio Buttons are always shown with a bullet when the field hasn't got the focus!
Even if the normal appearance is overwritten with a cross. When Printing or Interacting the cross is visible, but not after leaving the field. Foxit Reader respects the normal appearance. Nevertheless it should also look good in Adobe Reader.
When adding kids to the check box the kids are checked but I need to uncheck the others. I've no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution with iText 7:

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // RadioButton with cross instead of bullet.
    final String filename = "SampleRadioButton.pdf";
    final float boxLength = 20;
    final float crossWidth = 1;
    final String[] languages = { "Dutch", "English", "French" };
    try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filename); PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer); Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc)) {
        pdfDoc.addNewPage();
        final PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        final PdfButtonFormField radioGroup = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(pdfDoc, "Language", languages[1]);
        int count = 0;
        for (final String language : languages) {
            count++;
            // button
            final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 800 - (count * 30), boxLength, boxLength);
            final PdfFormField radioButton = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdfDoc, rect, radioGroup, language);
            final PdfDictionary radioDict = radioButton.getPdfObject();
            final PdfDictionary mk = new PdfDictionary();
            mk.put(PdfName.CA, new PdfString("8")); // check=4, circle=1, cross=8, diamond=u, square=n, star=H
            radioDict.put(PdfName.MK, mk);
            radioButton.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
            editAppearance(pdfDoc, radioButton, language, boxLength, crossWidth);
            // text
            final Paragraph para = new Paragraph(language).setFontSize(18);
            doc.showTextAligned(para, 70, 800 - (count * 30), TextAlignment.LEFT);
        }
        form.addField(radioGroup);
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filename));
}

private static void editAppearance(PdfDocument pdfDoc, PdfFormField radioButton, String value, float length, float crossWidth) {
    final PdfStream streamOn = (PdfStream) new PdfStream().makeIndirect(pdfDoc);
    final PdfCanvas canvasOn = new PdfCanvas(streamOn, new PdfResources(), pdfDoc);
    final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, length, length);
    final PdfFormXObject xObjectOn = new PdfFormXObject(rect);
    canvasOn.saveState();
    canvasOn.setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK).setLineWidth(crossWidth);
    // bottom left to top right
    canvasOn.moveTo(0, 0).lineTo(length, length).stroke();
    // Top left to bottom right
    canvasOn.moveTo(0, length).lineTo(length, 0).stroke();
    canvasOn.restoreState();
    xObjectOn.getPdfObject().getOutputStream().writeBytes(streamOn.getBytes());
    final PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = radioButton.getWidgets().get(0);
    widget.setNormalAppearance(new PdfDictionary());
    widget.getNormalAppearanceObject().put(new PdfName(value), xObjectOn.getPdfObject());
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I've been searching all over for this solution, and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to fix your current code. The following example creates 3 radiobuttons and all contain a cross. It was based on itext 5 and you may have to adapt it a bit for itext 7.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
        document.open();

        RadioCheckField bt = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(261, 576, 279, 594), "radio", "value1");
        bt.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CROSS);
        bt.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
        //bt.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID);
        bt.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        bt.setTextColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        bt.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THIN);
        bt.setChecked(false);
        PdfFormField f1 = bt.getRadioField();
        bt.setOnValue("value2");
        bt.setChecked(true);
        bt.setBox(new Rectangle(287, 577, 305, 595));
        PdfFormField f2 = bt.getRadioField();
        bt.setChecked(false);
        PdfFormField top = bt.getRadioGroup(true, false);
        bt.setOnValue("value3");
        bt.setBox(new Rectangle(314, 578, 332, 596));
        PdfFormField f3 = bt.getRadioField();
        top.addKid(f1);
        top.addKid(f2);
        top.addKid(f3);
        writer.addAnnotation(top);
        document.close();
```

Update: Here is your code with **iText7** however there seems to be a **bug** so that the check style is not changed for radiobuttons. Maybe the itext guys can say more...

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("output7.pdf"));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

PdfButtonFormField radioGroup = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(pdfDoc, "ExampleGroup", "");
radioGroup.setPage(1);

pdfDoc.addNewPage();

PdfFormField field1 = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(261, 576, 18, 18), radioGroup, "value1");
field1.setCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS);
field1.setValue("value1");
field1.regenerateField();

PdfFormField field2 = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(287, 577, 18, 18), radioGroup, "value2");
field2.setCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS);
field2.regenerateField();

PdfFormField field3 = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(314, 578, 18, 18), radioGroup, "value3");
field3.setCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS);
field3.regenerateField();

PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).addField(radioGroup);
doc.close();
```

Comment: Many thanks! Absolutly great solution and works fine with iText5! You saved my day! Unfortunately "setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CROSS)" doesn't exist for radio buttons in iText7. But that's another problem.

Comment: Yes the method does exists however there seems to be a bug so that the resulting PDF only contains the round CHECK mark...

Comment: When changing the normal appearance to a cross via iText 7 setNormalAppearance(), Adobe Reader doesn't respect this special normal appearance when the field hasn't got the focus. Foxit Reader for example is absolutly fine with that. With your help, by creating a pdf with iText 5 containing a workaround, itext support found out that Adobe Reader is incorrectly pulling the normal appearance from the /CA entry in the /MK dictionary. So there is a way to have a cross (or other standard symbol) even in Adobe Reader! By the way, setCheckType() applies only to Checkbox not to RadioButton.

Comment: >By the way, setCheckType() applies only to Checkbox not to RadioButton.
Really? Are you certain? Seems like a bug to me since this was working in itext5...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I was in contact with iText support. The below solution is the only way to get a RadioButton with a cross or check instead of the standard bullet.

Comment: Thanks, You saved a lot of my time :)